# Why doesn't my time input field on Cordova not show on Android?

Tags: cordova

I have a Cordova app with the following HTML:

```
<input type="time" value="23:00" />
<input value="23:00" />
```

When tested in my desktop browser, both input fields show "23:00". However, when run on an Android phone, "23:00" only appears in the second field, not the time field. I can't tell if this is a bug with Cordova or with Android or whether it's a bug at all.

Comment: Can you isolate which of the two is problematic?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Can I use...Support page for date and time input types](http://caniuse.com/#search=time), Android Browser doesn't support this on Android OSes earlier than 4.4. (It's also not supported in IE, Safari, or Firefox.)

That's probably why it doesn't work. It's not a Cordova bug. Try testing on your desktop in a browser other than Chrome.

Comment: All desktop browsers work. My Android phone is on Lollipop, but what browser engine is Cordova using? Maybe it's out of date? How can I tell?

Comment: I'm not sure. [The docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/) say it uses a web view. I would guess it uses the browser from the phone OS, since it doesn't ship with a browser included in it.

Comment: @Rchard Eng: It is not a cordova issue, it is an issue of the os. Cordova uses the build in webviews. What you can do is to use some kind of mask js-plugin.

Comment: Bizarre. If Cordova is using the same browser engine as Lollipop's own browser, then we can't blame the brower 'cuz it displays the time in both input fields. This **seems** to be very specific to Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the "time" type of input is not supported on the mobile browser you're using:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime